# Swagger and Spring boot - failed to load api definition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following `swagger` dependencies in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this config class in my application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("title")
                .description("desc")
                .version("1")
                .build();
    }

}
```

When I load my `swagger` page in browser I get the below error, what is the issue here?

I am using `Spring boot 3` and `java 17` for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were issues when using `springfox-boot-starter` with spring-boot 3. Please see this thread https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3983 The following setup should work:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.exmaple</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```