# Getting exception while accessing v3/api-docs

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

`pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>9.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bc-fips</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>iSupportRestApi</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

below exception showing

: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/iSupportApi] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getExampleSetFlag()'
at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SchemaSerializer.serialize(SchemaSerializer.java:35) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SchemaSerializer.serialize(SchemaSerializer.java:13) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1572) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1273) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:1140) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
at io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json.pretty(Json.java:24) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.clone(ModelResolver.java:937) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:656) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.springdoc.core.converters.AdditionalModelsConverter.resolve(AdditionalModelsConverter.java:155) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.converters.FileSupportConverter.resolve(FileSupportConverter.java:69) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.converters.ResponseSupportConverter.resolve(ResponseSupportConverter.java:79) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.converters.SchemaPropertyDeprecatingConverter.resolve(SchemaPropertyDeprecatingConverter.java:92) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.converters.PolymorphicModelConverter.resolve(PolymorphicModelConverter.java:77) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:97) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverters.resolveAsResolvedSchema(ModelConverters.java:110) ~[swagger-core-jakarta-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at org.springdoc.core.utils.SpringDocAnnotationsUtils.extractSchema(SpringDocAnnotationsUtils.java:122) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.service.GenericParameterService.calculateSchema(GenericParameterService.java:373) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.service.RequestBodyService.buildRequestBody(RequestBodyService.java:281) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.service.RequestBodyService.calculateRequestBodyInfo(RequestBodyService.java:257) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.build(AbstractRequestService.java:343) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:504) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:664) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$calculatePath$11(OpenApiResource.java:235) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.calculatePath(OpenApiResource.java:216) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$getPaths$2(OpenApiResource.java:186) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.getPaths(OpenApiResource.java:165) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:366) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:140) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebMvcResource.java:117) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.MultipleOpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(MultipleOpenApiWebMvcResource.java:89) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at com.protech.api.oauth.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:107) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

[Swagger not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6NAO.png)

Comment: found the solution. click below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724044/swagger-and-spring-boot-failed-to-load-api-definition